# Separate certificates on a local machine for each service

Tags: certificates

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a separate certificate on a local machine, one for a heavy client and the another one for the web browser to be sure the correct client communicate with the web browser. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It's possible, but it wouldn't ensure that the correct client is using the correct certificate. Nor does it ensure that your client is being used to begin with.  All a certificate does is prove possession of the private key.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, it is.

A certificate is simply a file, and so is the corresponding private key. You can place multiple certificates with their private keys on a machine and point each software to a different certificate.